# Main.strings couldn't be opened because there is no such file

Tags: ios, objective-c, internationalization

What the project path for the **Main.strings**? I renamed the project and so i18n don't works. I can't build the my application. This Main.strings is generated automatically?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use identity and type for the selected file in Xcode, and set the file's location there.

[image]

Comment: But the file does not exist. I wanna to create the file and stores in path.

Comment: Why don't you just delete it from your project if you do not have the file? Regular projects do not have that file unless you create it.

Comment: It is a legacy project. I just need to rename the application and resubmit the apple store but when did it i18n stopped working and now I can no longer run the application .

Comment: Its necessary to keep the Base.lproj in my project or just to keep the en.lproj?

Comment: I think you need the Base as well. I am not sure though.